# Displaying an image dynamically in a html table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display an image in a table. This is what I have tried:

```
imgv = "/img/koala.jpg";
dcontent = "<table style='background-color:purple;'><tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'> Date </td>";
                    dcontent += "<tr><td style='width: 100px;'><img src="' + imgv + '"/></td>";
```

I am getting a compile time error in the second line:

> "; expected".

I tried many syntax like:

```
<img src=" + imgv + "/></td>
```

but nothing is getting compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct answer is replacing `"' + imgv + '"` with `'" + imgv + "'`

```
imgv = "/img/koala.jpg";
dcontent = '<table style="background-color:purple;"><tr><td style="width:     100px; color: red;"> Date </td>';
dcontent += "<tr><td style='width: 100px;'><img src='" + imgv + "'/></td>";
```

Comment: You still need to surround the `src` with double quotes. The `style` attributes as well. I suggest flipflopping the single and double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **replace** `"' + imgv + '"` with `'" + imgv + "'`,
because ' is stronger than ".
For example, when you create variable named foo:

```
var foo = "write sentence 'like' that";
```

in html
you will get just "write sentence that".

SOLUTION is to replace them, then

```
var foo = 'write sentence "like" that'
```

will output exactly
write sentence "like" that - nothing wrong :-)